# Covariance with a common term

Tags: mathematical-statistics, covariance

So I've been digging into the math of correlations and covariances and one of my articles mentioned finding the covariance by using the common component, specifically with regards to, say, $cov(A + B, C + B)$.

I know that 
$$Cov(A + B, C + D) = cov(A, C) + cov(A, D) + cov(B, C) + cov(B, D)$$
but it seems like there would be a simplification in this case, but I don't understand how just using the "common component" would come into play.

Any pointers?

Comment: Do you know that $A,B,C$ are independent or uncorrelated?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention
A, C are correlated ($corr = \rho$), I don't know the relationship with B
So I'm trying to see the effect on the covariance of adding another r.v. to both A and C

Comment: OK, then things are not going to simplify much.  If you assume that $B$ is uncorrelated with $A,C$, then $cov(A+B,C+B)=cov(A,C)+V(B)$.  This is because $V(B)=Cov(B,B)$.

Comment: Is it useful for you to formulate it this way $cov(A+B,C+B) = cov(A+B+C,B)+cov(A,C)$?